# Thymeleaf th:href invoking both a post and get

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Following [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) I have configured a controller to handle the display and validation of a very simple form. I am using a Thymeleaf th:href to link to the form.

```
<a th:href="@{/event/create}">Create Event</a>
```

The problem is that both the showForm() and checkEventForm() are being invoked one after the other upon clicking the link. The result is a quick redirect away from the form back to / since checkEventForm() is also processed.

Are both GET and POST meant to be processed??

The Link :

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ol>
      <li><a th:href="@{/}">Join Event</a></li>
      <li><a th:href="@{/event/create}">Create Event</a></li>
    </ol>   
</div>
```

MvcConfig :

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

}
```

CreateEventController :

```
@Controller
public class CreateEventController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/event/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(CreateEvent event) {
        return "createEvent";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/event/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkEventForm(@Valid CreateEvent event, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "createEvent";
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

Comment: The link with `th:href="@{/event/create}"` should only invoke the `showForm` method and nothing else. Are you sure that you don't have any other relevant code?

Comment: @geoand, thanks for the reply! I've added more information..

Comment: Would you be able to share the project? I can't see anything obvious that would point to why both are getting invoked

Comment: @geoand, after some digging it turned out to be nothing with my program at all! It was in fact a chrome extension (lastpass) that had an auto-saved password for localhost which was attempting an automatic login and submitting the form! Talk about driving yourself nuts............... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some digging it turned out to be nothing with my program at all! It was in fact a chrome extension (lastpass) that had an auto-saved password for localhost which was attempting an automatic login and submitting the form! Talk about driving yourself nuts!